# Passing Parameters in XML WebService in PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, xml, web-services

I am new to creating a web service. I have created a web servise in XML as below:

```
<?php

     $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','crmap');

     $query1="SELECT * FROM `crm_salesabsent_logsheet` WHERE `ab_date`=CURRENT_DATE()";
            $res=mysqli_query($con,$query1) or die(mysqli_error($con));
            $data= array();
            if(mysqli_num_rows($res)){
      while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
          $data[] = array('row1'=>$row1);
      }
            }



      header('Content-type: text/xml');
            echo '<posts>';
            foreach($data as $index => $row1) {
                if(is_array($row1)) {
                    foreach($row1 as $key => $value) {
                        echo '<',$key,'>';
                        if(is_array($value)) {
                            foreach($value as $tag => $val) {
                                echo '<',$tag,'>',htmlentities($val),'</',$tag,'>';
                            }
                        }
                        echo '</',$key,'>';
                    }
                }
            }
            echo '</posts>';
    ?>
```

I am not passing any parameters in date as i am taking Current_Date() as default. Now, I want user to select their desired date. I want to pass Date as parameter and show result of the query as per the entered date. Here is the Html Code I am trying to pass the date as parameter in MySQL query

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>/title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
    .dt{}

</style>
<script>

$(document).on('focus', '.dt', function() {$(this).datepicker({ dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy'});});  
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="log" method="get">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <th>Select Date</th><td><input name="date" id="date" value="" class="dt"></td>
   <tr><td><input type="submit" name="post"  id="post" value="Submit"></td></tr>
  </tr>
 </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But I am unable to do so as I am getting Error. Help and solution will be really appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can replace this line

```
$query1="SELECT * FROM `crm_salesabsent_logsheet` WHERE `ab_date`=CURRENT_DATE()";
```

With this two lines

```
$date=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['date']));
$query1="SELECT * FROM `crm_salesabsent_logsheet` WHERE `ab_date`='{$date}'";
```

Comment: Sorry, but this did not answer my question of how to get the values from input field from html to xml

Answer (score 0):

To place the posted date into your XML you can add a line like this:

```
echo '<posts>';
echo '<posted_date>' . date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['date'])) . '</posted_date>';
```